# how to loop and view multiple image in HTML by typescript?

Tags: html, css, typescript

Currently I'm writing a program that have  tag inside html to receive images from file, after that I encounter a problem that I can't loop how many images that user select, I'm new to typescript can some one teach me ? or provide a  tutorial link for me ?? Below is my code

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple" onchange="document.getElementById('blah').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])">

<img src="#" id="blah" width="150" height="150" align="middle"/>
```

I only can view and load 1 image at a time, can I know how to loop inside typescript and use .innerHtml to create  something like that ?? I can only do it in HTML , my typescript does'nt work..I'm new to it

Thanks !!

my CSS :

```
img[src="#"] {
   display: none;
}


img {
    image-orientation: from-image;
}
```

and 1 more question, why my image-orientation is not working ??

**Edit

I have found some code in the webpages, and I would like to implement inside my typescript, how can I do that ??

```
window.onload = function(){   
    //Check File API support
    if(window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader)
    {
        $('#files').live("change", function(event) {
            var files = event.target.files; //FileList object
            var output = document.getElementById("result");
            for(var i = 0; i< files.length; i++)
            {
                var file = files[i];
                //Only pics
                // if(!file.type.match('image'))
                if(file.type.match('image.*')){
                    if(this.files[0].size < 2097152){    
                  // continue;
                    var picReader = new FileReader();
                    picReader.addEventListener("load",function(event){
                        var picFile = event.target;
                        var div = document.createElement("div");
                        div.innerHTML = "<img class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
                                "title='preview image'/>";
                        output.insertBefore(div,null);            
                    });
                    //Read the image
                    $('#clear, #result').show();
                    picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
                    }else{
                        alert("Image Size is too big. Minimum size is 2MB.");
                        $(this).val("");
                    }
                }else{
                alert("You can only upload image file.");
                $(this).val("");
            }
            }                               

        });
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Your browser does not support File API");
    }
}

   $('#files').live("click", function() {
        $('.thumbnail').parent().remove();
        $('result').hide();
        $(this).val("");
    });

    $('#clear').live("click", function() {
        $('.thumbnail').parent().remove();
        $('#result').hide();
        $('#files').val("");
        $(this).hide();
    });
```

Below is the code, can I know how can this be implement into my TS ?? 
I have tried it , all seems like it is not working ..

Here is the jsfiddle example where I get from it.

http://jsfiddle.net/2xES5/28/

Comment: Hi, would you please post your typescript code?

Comment: I don't have any typescript code, because I don't know how to write it. I have done this in HTML method, but I wish to view multiple image, so I need to call a typescript function and I don't know how to do it. I'm new to typescript. Sorry

Comment: The code you're using is javascript, and all valid Javascript code is valid Typescript code.  Until you learn the [Typescript language](http://www.typescriptlang.org/), you may consider just sticking with Javascript - which is more widely documented and requires no extra build steps - which is probably the think you're getting hung up on.

Comment: You really need to learn about the basic concepts. The code you've added is not HTML, it is Javascript. Typescript is a programming language that gets compiled into javascript, so you can use typescript instead of javascript to write code for Web front-end if you like to use object-oriented concept and higher level of abstraction, but you're certainly not required to. You can as well stick to good old javascript and implement anything you want. So the question is why are you referring to typescript in your question?

Comment: I have no idea also. I saw the file come with .ts I thought I need to be use something like typescript, ok if it was like what you guys said, means that all of the JS code I can put inside a TS file and it won't occur any error ? I've tried it before and quite many errors occur, for example the jsfiddle above, I implement it and the first coding is already error. the window.onload() is not working, the TS compiler only give the error "; is expected" I have no idea why ? Anything can help me ?

Comment: use plain js , your code seems nothing like you need to use typescript , it is all plain jquery and javascript , typescript is for building web applications and it is just a overuse in here since this can be done pretty nicely with a simple jquery and javascript with minimal complexity

Comment: Can't I have other web application function that connects through typescript, so I must use the JS above inside my typescript, I have solve quite many of the problem now what I face is 

Property 'live' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.

Anyone know how to solve this ???